# Setting up CAN FD communication between laptop(python script) and controller via PCAN

Tags: python, embedded, can-bus

I'm trying to set up a CAN FD communication between my laptop and a controller via [PCAN-USB Prof FD](https://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-USB-Pro-FD.366.0.html?&L=1). On my laptop I'm running a python script that's using the [python-can](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library to set up the communication. The controller is an RH850.

I assume that the communication works fine on the controller side since it works with both CANoe and PCAN View.

Now onto the problem. I have set up the script to use the pcan interface and used all the necessary arguments to set the nominal and data bit rate (took them from PCAN View) so it looks something like this:

```
bus = pcan.PcanBus('PCAN_USBBUS1', fd=True, other_can_fd_params = values_from_PCAN_view)
```

Using the diagnostic services seems to work fine, but receving normal CAN frames throws back an error:

```
PcanCanOperationError: A received message is invalid
```

Any tips, suggestions or improvements are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ever get this working? I've tried setting bitrate+data_bitrate, as well as the detailed timing parameters referenced PCANBasic API docs. No luck getting it actually working ☹️

Comment: Hello @BrianMcFarland, if I remember correctly we managed to get it running but we stopped using it because it was not fitting our requirements. I'll take a look at the code once I'm in the office and hopefully I can give you an answer in a few days. Hang in there, buddy! Until then, here is some documentation that we used:  [can-isotp](https://can-isotp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) ,[udsoncan](https://udsoncan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [python-can](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Comment: I actually found that hacking up can.interfaces.pcan.pcan a little bit, I could just log a warning on the "Illegal data" warning (just like busy heavy/bus-light) and it more or less works.  I get these errors about 1x per second for a minute  or so and then they stop. doesn't seem to have any impact on bus operation for my purposes of doing a basic bus keep-alive + monitoring/setting a small handful of signals.